# Print out array index in writeline command

Tags: c#

How to print the array index in a writeline command:
example:

```
 Console.WriteLine(" array[j] = {0}", array[j]);
```

Wanted output:

```
array[1]= value1
array[2]= value2
array[3]= value3
```

.
.

Comment: You know that arrays are zero based, that means the first index is 0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine` has a format-like syntax, so to say, to accept multiple parameters and to put them into the format string. So:

```
Console.WriteLine("array[{0}] = {1}", j, array[j]);
```

Which is basically another way of writing:

```
string line = String.Format("array[{0}] = {1}", j, array[j]);
Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
for(int i=0;i<array.Length;i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(String.Format(" array[{0}] = {1}", i,array[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using foreach..

```
 int[] array = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };          
 foreach (var arr in array.Select((val, index) => new { val, index }))
 {
   Console.WriteLine("array[{0}]={1}", arr.index, arr.val);
 }
```